# How to use spiderable with a meteor app hosted on modulus.io

Tags: ssl, meteor, modulus

I'm trying to make spiderable works on my meteor app hosted on modulus with SSL.
I have Meteor 1.0, iron:router 1.0, spiderable and node package of phantomjs

All is working on localhost. But once I deploy on Modulus, first I had the error

```
spiderable: phantomjs failed: null
```

Then, I added the following environment variable in the modulus panel:

```
METEOR_PKG_SPIDERABLE_PHANTOMJS_ARGS = --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --debug=true
```

This is still not working and the debug is outputting multiple times (like it's looping over an error) the following message in the modulus console:

```
2014-12-03T17:01:00 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {
if (typeof Meteor === 'undefined'
    || Meteor.status === undefined
    || !Meteor.status().connected) {
  return false;
}
if (typeof Package === 'undefined'
    || Package.spiderable === undefined
    || Package.spiderable.Spiderable === undefined
    || !Package.spiderable.Spiderable._initialSubscriptionsStarted) {
  return false;
}
Tracker.flush();
return DDP._allSubscriptionsReady();
})(); })()" 
2014-12-03T17:01:00 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(bool, false)
```

If anyone knows how to solve this or succeeded to deploy a meteor project on modulus.io with SSL and spiderable. Let's me know the good way to do it :)

Thank a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

1. I installed phantomjs locally and run the test script available at http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable/

   phantomjs phantomtest.js

This gave me more details about the error: Parse Error.
Then, it was a javascript file that once compiled/minified, rendered an error caused by select2. The js library that was using it was flat-ui.js (http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/).

I discover this by testing many deploys on *.meteor.com and by adding/removing .js file.

2. I edit the flat-ui.js library to avoid Parsing Error.
3. I redeployed on both modulus.io and *.meteor.com. All was working fine on *.meteor.com but still didn't work on modulus.io. That let me thinking about an SSL error but I only saw "spiderable: phantomjs failed: null" in the modulus.io logs.
4. I add the following environment variable in the modulus panel:

   METEOR_PKG_SPIDERABLE_PHANTOMJS_ARGS = --debug=true

and it appears that it was a "SSL Handshake error":

```
[DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 6 ( "SSL handshake failed" )
```

5. I add another option to the METEOR_PKG_SPIDERABLE_PHANTOMJS_ARGS environment variable:

   METEOR_PKG_SPIDERABLE_PHANTOMJS_ARGS = --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --debug=true

Now everything is working fine on modulus.io.

To sumup:

- solve javascript errors
- add METEOR_PKG_SPIDERABLE_PHANTOMJS_ARGS = --ignore-ssl-errors=yes

I hope this will help some dudes,

Comment: Thank you, METEOR_PKG_SPIDERABLE_PHANTOMJS_ARGS = --ignore-ssl-errors=yes   - was very helpful